# AngularJs multi level data drilling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm kind of a newbie in AngularJs and I have a complex JSON that i need to get data from to a auto complete.

[image]

I need to create an auto complete for ONLY the child elements in the the stucture without showing the parent categories.

Getting to the parents is easy, data[2].JobCategories and binding that to the ng-repeat and binding "jobParentCategoryModel.JobCategoryName" to the model does the trick.

But drilling to get only the children confuses me in the angular way. The way i see it, what I need to so is to to get only the children from the factory in new array of categories children and work with that. But for some reason in my mind it seem wrong to drill in the factory... Don't know why, just doesn't seem the angular way to do things.

PS. When looking at examples i saw lots of nested ng-repeat examples but i don't want to create the extra parent DOM elements for each child, so using nested repeats seams over head. But again I don't want to destroy the data structure (It is not two way binding so I don't know if it matter if i change the model at all).

What is the best practice to do this kind of deep drill down in angular?

Comment: Where do you want to do this? It is not really Angular specific?

Comment: As i said, I know i can do it in the factory and return the new data structure but I want to know if there is an angular way to do it. I Know that factory is also "The angular way" but i mean do i do it in the JS side but manipulating the data or in the template side? or maybe i didn't understand the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to use only the child elements for instance in an ng-repeat but you do not want to create a separate data structure, that holds only these elements, in your scope. In this case I would write a function that extracts the elements and refer to this function in the ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="eachElement in getChildElements()">...</li>
```

This way you avoid redundancy and inconsistencies since your list automatically adapts to changes in the data structure.

Comment: Great, Didn't think about it this way, that i can user function in the repeat and just return the data i want.